# 'float' object is not subscriptable in column

Tags: python, pandas, function

I want to change some values on my dataframe (actually my dataframe is using pandas library). then i made a function and i was using apply to change this column. After I run it, there is appear that 'float' object is not subscriptable in column'. i'm confused right now because, before i am starting this question, there are some similar questions from another, and I think that's not solving my problem

this is mine :

```
def true_latitude(Latitude):
    if Latitude > 1.5:
        return Latitude * (-1.0)
    else:
        return Latitude

df['Latitude'] = df['Latitude'].apply(lambda x : true_latitude (x['Latitude']),)
```

Comment: What is the full error message? And what line causes the error? Please [edit] your questiont o include this.

Comment: try just : `df['Latitude'] = df['Latitude'].apply(lambda x : true_latitude(x))` ..?

Answer (score 2):

assuming your `Latitude` column contains float values. Since you are applying the changes to a single column (`df['Latitude'].apply(...`) there's no need to do `x['Latitude']` again.
You can do:

```
df['Latitude'] = df['Latitude'].apply(lambda x : true_latitude(x))
```

or even

```
df['Latitude'] = df['Latitude'].apply(true_latitude)
```

Comment: Or if the function really is that simple... `df.loc[df['Latitude'] > 1.5, 'Latitude'] *= -1.0`